# how to fill NaN values of Pandas column with values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with missing values after a certain number of rows, and another column with missing values up to that point.  How can I join the two columns so that I have one column with all the values?

Columns as is:

```
         COL 1      COL 2 
0            A        NaN
1            B        NaN  
2            C        NaN 
3          NaN          D   
4          NaN          E
5          NaN          F
```

Expected output:

```
         COL 1      
0            A             
1            B             
2            C            
3            D           
4            E          
5            F
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['COL 1'] = df['COL 1'].fillna(df['COL 2'])
```

---

```
df['COL 1'] = df['COL 1'].combine_first(df['COL 2'])
```

If want also remove second column add [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df['COL 1'] = df['COL 1'].fillna(df.pop('COL 2'))
#df['COL 1'] = df['COL 1'].combine_first(df.pop('COL 2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use fillna() with 'COL2' values on 'COL1' and then drop 'COL2'

```
df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].fillna(df['COL2'])
df = df.drop(columns='COL2')
```